# "Toggle Comment" for .htaccess files in Netbeans 7.x?

Tags: .htaccess, netbeans, comments, toggle, syntax-highlighting

Is there any way to get the ***Toggle Comment*** command working for .htaccess files in Netbeans 7.2? I already got used to the according keyboard shortcuts in php, css, js and css files. As syntax highlighting is supported in 7.2, maybe it's possible to achieve that by changing the config?

[image]

**EDIT**: I am not limited to Netbeans 7.2

Answer (score 2):

Are you strictly limited to Netbeans v7.2? If not, you can make use of the latest builds. It was announced earlier.

https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/toggling_comments

Comment: Nice. That's bascially the answer. I will go for 7.3 as soon as possible then.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has not been implemented in the current stable release of 7.3. The dev build I downloaded following the link is unstable on my system (win7-64). Will have to wait a few more weeks I guess.